# ValueError on mmap - Python

Tags: python, mmap

I'm trying to mmap a file like this:

```
f= open('file.txt', 'r')
data= mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
```

But I get:

```
 data= mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
ValueError: mmap offset is greater than file size
```

After searching for this, I still can't figure out what's wrong and the weird thing is, this was working half an hour ago! Any help?

Comment: Check whether your file is empty??

Comment: @RohitJain Ahh you're right. was working with so many files didn't notice this. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am moving this from my comment, as it was helpful to OP..

You need to check whether your file is empty.. `mmap.mmap` throws exception, if the file in the parameter is empty..

Check the documentation -> http://docs.python.org/library/mmap.html

Comment: Looks like file was overwritten and became blank. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to this error when using mode='r' while trying to read a memmap from a file for the first time (as a way of sort of declaring that part of the file is a memmap). In this case, numpy tries to read data from the file, realizes the file isn't long enough, and tries to extend the file so the new memmap can sit there. It took me a while to realize numpy can't extend the file this way without write privileges.